# why should we prefer to do it on our own instead of using AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, afnetworking

Actually I am new to iOS,I want to parse JSON, I have done it by using sync and async , NSURLConnection Methods and got the solution. But I have noticed that the same work can be done through AFNetworking by importing third party classes. I have tried this.

```
str_BaseUrl = @"https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str_BaseUrl];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
    obj_array = (NSMutableArray *)responseObject;
    [obj_table reloadData];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                  alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert"
                                  message:@" Error"
                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* yesButton = [UIAlertAction
                                actionWithTitle:@"Ok"
                                style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                {


                                }];
    [alert addAction:yesButton];


    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];



}];
[operation start];
```

It works fine. But I have a confusion why we use AFNetworking.

Comment: [this](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) page should help you find the answer.

Comment: There is no need to use AFNetworking or a similar library, especially for simple tasks. Also AFNetworking has its own problems (every library does).  But we do it to save time. However, the first time you should probably try to write the code by yourself (you should understand what a library does under the hood). The second time go for a library. It will save you development time (= money). It's not only the time to implement code, it's also the maintenance time.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that: it saves your time, and it is very good and is still getting better day by day.
I think your question should be like this: why should we prefer to do it on our own instead of using AFNetworking?